# Ajax json response not getting appended to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I want to append a json object to the page. I get it successfully via ajax, but it's not showing up.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
{% csrf_token %}
   Search:<input type="text" name="artist" id="artist" />
    <button class="updateButton" onclick="createlist()">submit</button>
</form>

function createlist(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/rest/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        artist: $('#artist').val()
    },
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFTOKEN': "{{ csrf_token }}",
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#output').html(data); //also tried data.content
    }
});
}
```

The response appears to be in one long escaped string when I view the response and preview in devtools.

```
"[{\"fields\": {\"artist\": \"Leonardo da Vinci\", \"link\": \"https://trove2.storage.googleapis.com/leonardo-da-vinci/galloping-rider-and-other-figures.jpg\", \"title\": \"Galloping Rider and other figures\"}, \"model\": \"serve.art\", \"pk\": 63057}
```

How can I wrangle this into something usable?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
JSON.parse
```

and you'll get the data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Still not appending the data to the page when I do that. `$('#output').html(JSON.parse(data));` not showing up.

Comment: sorry probably misread your question. set a break point and see if $('#output') is getting the element

Comment: It's working now, but I changed nothing, all I did was set a breakpoint and step through the function in devtools. That's weird, I wonder what fixed it.

Comment: probably browser was reading cache or something. great if everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot append an **object** to a HTML element.

Don't parse the **JSON**, just append in the format(**string**) as you are getting.

I have tried and successfully appended to the HTML element but in the **string** format.

Comment: Me too, it magically started working when I set a breakpoint on the success function and stepped through it in devtools.

Answer (score 1):

you should try like this:

```js
var output=""; 
  var data="[{\"fields\": {\"artist\": \"Leonardo da Vinci\", \"link\": \"https://trove2.storage.googleapis.com/leonardo-da-vinci/galloping-rider-and-other-figures.jpg\", \"title\": \"Galloping Rider and other figures\"}, \"model\": \"serve.art\", \"pk\": 63057}]";
 data =  JSON.parse(data)
for(x in data){
 console.log(data[x]);
output=output+"Artist:"+data[x].fields.artist+"<br>"+"Link:"+data[x].fields.link+"<br>"+"Title:"+data[x].fields.title+"<br>"+"Model:"+data[x].model+"<br>"+"PK:"+data[x].pk+"<br>";
 
}
   $('#output').html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="output"></div>
```

Comment: That code wasn't working for me until I ran devtools and set breakpoints and whatnot. Now it works. What is wrong with my browser that it keeps doing this?